# wxPython GUI - can it be compared to Java GUI or Visual Studio GUI?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a two years of experience in programming of enterprise application's  with Java and Visual Studio, and I'm new in Python and wxPython. So my question is: Can wxPython provide me enough rich GUI to create those same app's? My reason if using Python is in it's diversity, simplicity and fast development of app's. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it depends on your definition of "rich."  I use it and like to think it can make some fairly useful GUIs.  Here's a screenshot of a wxPython app to work with sensor data I'm writing right now - not the most elaborate or complicated in the world, but so far it seems fairly intuitive for users:

[image: NDIToolbox Windows 7 screenshot]

I find the [wxPython docs](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx-module.html) to be a little sparse at times, but as long as you've got the [demo](http://wxpython.org/download.php) installed and  the [wxWidgets docs](http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/) open it's a good toolkit to use.

Comment: wxPython is a non-Pythonic wrapper around wxWidgets, I found myself reading the wxWidgets docs at all times.

Comment: The wxPython docs are nearly worthless. The wxWidgets docs and the wxPyhton wiki are the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

wxGlade will give you the GUI skeleton. You will still need a separate text editor (I recommend Geany) to fill in the handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I would certainly suggest using Python and its GUI libraries, but only you can really make the decision as to wether you think its better than visual studio or Java. The syntax of Python is very basic and I think many people can agree its a plesure to use when you get your head around it (no curly brackets etc). Python Tkinter is quite a simple GUI library and its ideal for making a basic application. WxPython on the other hand is far more advanced than Tkinter hence a richer user experience. The only problem I have had while using Wx is not being able to find suitable examples on the web to demonstarte how some things are done. Good luck, hope you find what your looking for. Karl

Comment: I don't think "more advanced" is the right description. wxPython has a bigger library of built-in widgets but that is only better if you need those widgets. Just recently I switched a project from wxPython to Tkinter because it was just too hard to do in wxPython.

Comment: @BryanOakley I found my self having to switch to Tkinter aswell! Cant go wrong with Tk if im honest.

Comment: @BryanOakley you leave me astounded. What can be done with tkinter that can not be done easier, faster and prettier in wxPython ? (except py3k gui). Using wxglade + subclassing, to build a wx aplication, simple or complex, is really fast and efficient, maintenable and extendable...

Comment: @joaquin: comments aren't an appropriate place to answer a question like that. Suffice it to say I think both toolkits are better at some things, worse at others.

Comment: Bryan Oakley has used Tk for like 10+ years. He's a little biased.

Answer (score 0):

The [wxPython demo](http://wxpython.org/download.php) shows most of the widgets that are available.  I suggest that you take a look at this and see whether it will do what you need.